# Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

In MySQL, I have just made this trigger to set the last modified date of one table if a new record relating to it is inserted into a linking table

```
create trigger trg_badge after insert on tbl_badge for each row 
UPDATE tbl_sub_model SET last_modified_date = NOW() 
WHERE sub_model_sk = NEW.sub_model_sk;
```

When I run a script that fills `tbl_sub_model` then `tbl_badge` I get:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'tbl_sub_model' in stored 
function/trigger because it is already used by statement which 
invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Things work fine when I insert using a separate script but just not if both statements are in the same script. is there a way of inserting into both tables with the same .sql script?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on `tbl_sub_model` that inserts into `tbl_badge`?

Comment: no, there's a foreign key on tbl_badge referencing tbl_sub_model though. my suspicion is that the sql script is somehow locking tbl_sub_model from being edited by the trigger because it was inserting into it earlier but don't know how to separate the commands

Comment: +1 for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... solved it, my insert statement was joining tbl_sub_model to a couple of other ones in order to get the sub_model_sk relating to the correct new records.

Now I know that I'll just create the triggers at the end of the script, no biggie.